# Does Phabricator Conduit API support edit comment/transaction?

Tags: phabricator

I come across a project in which I have to develop a tool to update the comment of a Maniphest task.

I have searched across the Phabricator Conduit API page, but I can only find APIs for applying new transactions.

Is there any API or workaround to edit a comment/transaction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "/transaction" in the title can be a bit confusing, since a Transaction in Phabricator is literally every change in every aspect of every object. Maybe we can remove "/transaction" from the title, since here we are clearly interested in editing comments (that will involve a new transaction - so it's not about editing an existing transaction)

Comment: I see "comment" in the title but I'm quite sure this question is about Task description (the editable field under the title), not comments (the comments that anyone can put like "Yeah I'm working on it" etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`maniphest.edit`](https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/maniphest.edit/) with a transaction type of `description`, like so:

```sh
curl https://secure.phabricator.com/api/maniphest.edit \
    -d api.token=api-token \
    -d transactions[0][type]=description \
    -d transactions[0][value]=My%20new%20task%20description \
    -d objectIdentifier=1
```